# How to break onFileSelect in fileSelect and fileUpload function in Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I need to trigger upload files in `fileUpload` function,  where I am able to use string to append to formData payload to something like this.

```
"params": [ filepath+files[i].name, { "mode": "493" }]
```

and then do the upload which is happening in fileSelect function itself.

I am an Angular beginner.

`.ts` part of the component.

```
constructor(
    protected ws: WebSocketService, protected http: Http, private loader: AppLoaderService,
    private dialog:DialogService, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {

  }
fileUpload(filepath: string): void {
  //need help to trigger upload files in this function, 
  // where I am able to use string to append to formData 
  // payload to something like this.
  // "params": [ filepath+files[i].name, { "mode": "493" }]
  // and then do the upload which is happening in fileSelect fucntion itself.
  //
  // this.http.post(this.apiEndPoint, formData).subscribe(
  //   (data) => {
  //     this.loader.close();
  //     this.snackBar.open("your files are uploaded", 'close', { duration: 5000 })
  //   },
  //   (error) => {
  //     this.loader.close();
  //     this.dialog.errorReport(error.status, error.statusText, error._body);
  //   }
  // );


}
fileSelect(event: EventTarget) {
  this.loader.open();

  const eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext>event;
  const target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>eventObj.target;
  const files: FileList = target.files;

  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('file', files[i]);
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify({
      "method": "filesystem.put",
      "params": ["/tmp/"+files[i].name, { "mode": "493" }]
    }))
  }
  this.http.post(this.apiEndPoint, formData).subscribe(
     (data) => {
       this.loader.close();
       this.snackBar.open("your files are uploaded", 'close', { duration: 5000 })
     },
     (error) => {
       this.loader.close();
       this.dialog.errorReport(error.status, error.statusText, error._body);
     }
   );
}
```

`.html` part of the component.

```
 <mat-card-content>
    <input type="file" (change)="fileSelect($event)" placeholder="select a file to Upload" accept=".iso">
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="fileUpload()">Upload</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
```

Comment: So what is your issue?

Comment: issue is when I am using fileSelect I am uploading the file right after I select a file, I want to break this process in two part, 1) select a file and then 2) upload the file when I hit upload button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging into other approaches as well, the answer was way simpler than I was expecting,
I had created a `template reference variable` called
`<input type="file" #fileInput accept="{{config.acceptedFiles}}">`
and access that variable in component 
`export class FormUploadComponent {
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput;
.....
upload(location = "/tmp/") {
const fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
......
}`

the keys is to use `@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput;` and access it throughout the component.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `this.http.post` code in your fileSelect method which is why it is happening straight after you select a file.

Extract that out into your fileUpload method.

Declare the formData outside of the function as a property of the component so you can access it from the fileUpload method.

```
private formData: FormData;
```

Comment: hrrm, well I know that but do you know how can I extract that file variable in `fileSelect` to `fileUpload` ?

Comment: declare a private variable in your component and assign it in the fileSelect method

Comment: this approach did not work for me, instead I used  `@ViewChild` approach as mentioned in my answer.